# concatenate Text for asp:Label

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am working on an asp webforms site.
I found a label that has a Text property that is huge.
Looks like...

```
asp:Label runat="server" Text="A book of text that keeps going...."
/asp:Label
```

I tried seperating it with " + " and " & " inbetween, so I could have it looks like a paragraph in the .aspx page.

And suggestions on howto better organize this text and not make it so ugly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the Text property. You can just put the text inside the tags.

```
<asp:Label runat="server">
   A book of text that keeps going...
</asp:Label>
```

Or use a resource file. That puts the strings in a separate file, which is also useful for localization. See: [Using Resources for Localization with ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx)